# Where to write console.log inside component ? react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to check my variables:

```
  return (
    <FileInfo> 
      <div>
        <FileSize>{fileSize}</FileSize> 
      </div>
    </FileInfo>
  );
};

const FilesContainer = ({ intl, files, onClickHandler, fullWidth }) => (
  <Container>
    <Label>
      {files} 
    </Label> 
  </Container>
);
```

I need to check my :

const FilesContainer = ({ intl, files, onClickHandler, fullWidth }) => (

my files variable ... when I console.log('files' , files) bellow example:

```
const FilesContainer = ({ intl, files, onClickHandler, fullWidth }) => (
  console.log('files' , files)
  <Container>
    <Label>
      {files} 
    </Label> 
  </Container>
);
```

I got error...how to check var ?

Comment: Make it `=> { console.log("files", files); return <Container>...</Container> }`

Comment: If you need to debug your application, I highly recommend using a [debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/). The console is for logging.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implicit inline return, Use the function block and add console logs before the return statement.

```
const FilesContainer = ({ intl, files, onClickHandler, fullWidth }) => {
  console.log("files", files);
  return (
    <Container>
      <Label>{files}</Label>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -3):

Missing comma:

```js
const FilesContainer = ({ intl, files, onClickHandler, fullWidth }) => (
  console.log('files' , files),
  <Container>
    <Label>
      {files} 
    </Label> 
  </Container>
);
```

Comment: What? Isn't that a solution?